# Expression Blend 3 launch error

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, expression-blend

I've made a fresh install of Expression Blend 3 on Windows 7 64-Bit Ultimate and every time I create a brand new Silverlight 3 Application + Website project in Expression Blend 3 then try and run it I get the error:

Could not start "http://localhost:63523/Default.html" due to the following error: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:Application not found

Blend is using the Microsoft Expression Development Server and the icon for the server starts and shows in the system tray so I know it's running. When clicking Show Details on the icon I can see that the physical path is set correctly to the path of the project. The Default.html file exists in the folder that the Expression Development Server is pointing too.

Comment: Do you have any previous projects (or sample ones), do they run ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this was caused by the file association for .url filetype was set to Microsoft Browser rather than Internet Explorer/FireFox. I fixed this by going to Control Panel, Default Programs, Associate a file type or protocol with a program, then selecting .url and navigating to the Firefox.exe executable

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar set up as you (x64, Windows 7 Ultimate, Blend 3) and while I haven't had your particular issue with Blend, I have had others (Catastrophic errors being the norm).

Maybe a reinstall will do the trick? Sorry, I know it's trite.

Comment: I've reinstalled several times, but the same error occurs every time I create a new blank project and just try running it. :-(